# CONVERT_TZ functions on a shared hosted server

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

I this I would really like to use the CONVERT_TZ function to handle sending out automated reminders via cron jobs written in Perl.  The problem I'm having is that anytime I use the CONVERT_TZ function I get a NULL output which leads me to believe that my host doesn't have the timezone tables populated.  Unfortunately they are being less then helpful with setting this up for me so I attempted to load these tables into my database since I don't have access to the system mysql database, but this doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Anyone know how to address this issue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?